# Virtual machines on external drives and possible damages

Tags: hard-drive, usb, virtualization

I want to ask you, If my computer or external hardware components can be damaged if I use an external HDD for working with my virtual machines.

External disks are meant to store a lot of data, but not to constantly read and write small files. This could cause problems, I'm afraid.

Can I still safely run my virtual machines from a standard, external HDD hard drive, without having to fear an immense wear of the HDD or the USB slot the HDD is connected on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most USB-connected HDDs are exactly the same standard 2.5" or 3.5" SATA HDDs as you'd find in a laptop or desktop computer – only with a SATA-to-USB converter inside the box. Fundamentally, they don't wear out any differently.

(That said, USB is noticeably *slower* than SATA, especially in terms of multiple queued requests. Using an external disk/adapter that supports UAS may help a little.)

The USB connection itself can be worn out only by physically plugging/unplugging the cable too many times, but it is completely unaffected by the electrical signals transferred over it; it's the same type of signal either way.

(Even the USB controller, which generates those signals, doesn't actually see the transfer in terms of "files": that's handled by the OS, so all the USB requests just look like "read sector X" or "write data Y to sector Z" regardless of what you're actually doing.)

Comment: I agree overall, and this is a bit of a nit-pik, I am not sure the "exactly the same standard" part is correct.  I'd expect external drives to be lower rotation, lower power drives - indeed https://www.blogtechtips.com/2016/10/27/how-to-open-a-western-digital-my-passport-external-hard-drive/ shows a WD green drive in a passport (at 2:15 in the video).  On  VM server you would have disks which are designed to handle much heavier loads then green drives. Green drives are very entry level and have a much lower endurance rating then Black ones, not even getting into RAID drives...

Comment: @davidgo: True, but if you compare to a standard desktop or even a laptop (as OP just mentions a computer, not a server) – those are nowhere near a "VM server" either, and I suspect a laptop's disk would be fairly similar to an enclosure disk (some mere 5400 rpm, probably low-power too).